# Independence and Conditional Independence

Tags: probability

Draw three cards randomly from a well-shuffled nine poker cards, from Club 2 to Club 10 with replacement. Let X be the sum of numbers on the first and the second cards, Y be the sum of numbers on the second and the third cards, and Z be the number on the second cards. Are X, Y independent? Are X, Y independent given Z? Justify your answer.

X & Y Independent: we must show P(X ∩ Y)= P(X)P(Y); however, I am struggling to find P(X ∩ Y). So far I have P(X)=P(Y)=36/84, but what is the probability of their intersection?

X & Y Independent given Z: similarly, I know I must show P(X ∩ Y|Z)=P(X|Z)P(Y|Z), but I am struggling to find each of those probabilities. Any suggestions?

Comment: $X,Y,Z$ are random variables : their intersection does not make sense, for example. What does make sense, is $P(X = m , Y = n)$ for some $m,n$. With that in mind, you must explain what $P(X) = P(Y) = \frac{36}{84}$ means.

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг I'm not exactly sure what you mean by explain what that means. It means that the probability of the sum of the first two chosen cards and the sum of the second two cards is 36/84. I'm still not clear on how to prove that X and Y are independent or not.

Comment: Must I just show that P(X and Y) = (36/84) + (36/84) is not equal to P(X)P(Y)?

Comment: Must I just show that P(X and Y) = (36/84) + (36/84) is not equal to P(X)P(Y)?

Comment: @Joanne X is a random variable, not an event.  $P(X)$ doesn't mean anything.  You need something like $P(X=3)$  I have no idea what you mean by $P(X)=36/84.$

Comment: @Joanne: Two random variables $X$ and $Y$ are independent if their joint cumulative probability distribution equals the product of their cumulative distribution functions, i.e., $F_{X,Y}(x,y) = F_X(x)F_Y(y)$. You can only assign probability to a random variable taking a particular value, or $P(X=x)$. $(X=x)$ is an event, $X$ itself isn't.

Comment: @Joanne A random variables takes a series of values with certain probabilities. You can ask for the probability that the variable takes a certain value : but you cannot ask for  the probability of that variable itself! For example, what is the probability that : "sum of numbers on first and second cards" does not make sense. What does make sense, is what is the probability that : "sum of numbers on first and second cards is $17$", for example. This distinction is key : before you understand the question itself, you should be clear  about this concept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be confused about what independence of random variables means.  $X$ and $Y$ are independent if $$P(X=x,Y=y)=P(X=x)P(Y=y)$$ for all values of $x$ and $y$.  For example, we need $$P(X=6,Y=6)=P(X=6)P(Y=6)$$  Is this true?  Since $X$ is the sum of the numbers on cards $1$ and $2$ and $Y$ is the sum of the numbers on cards $2$ and $3,$ we can only have $X=Y=6$ if the same number appears on cards $1$ and $3,$ which is impossible.  That is, $P(X=6,Y=6)=0.$  Clearly, it is possible for the sum of the two cards to be $6$ however, for one card could be $2$ and the other $4$.  Therefore, $P(X=6)P(Y=6)\neq 0,$ and the random variables are **not** independent.

For conditional independence, we need for all values of $x,y,z$ that $$P(X=x,Y=y|Z=z)=P(X=x|Z=z)P(Y=y|Z=z)$$  I'll leave it to you to work this one out.